# How to exclude filename from CSS Module added styles?

Tags: html, css, css-modules

When creating a stylesheet for a certain div using CSS Modules, the inspected style includes the filename of where the style originated from. For example, my header styling is in a file named `Header.module.css` and when it is applied to my header div it would read something like `Header_header-container-34jk`. I was wondering if there is any way to exclude the `Header_` from the front of the style so it just reads `header-container-34jk`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to edit [localidentname](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#localidentname) at webPack config